# What are the dimensions of a Minecraft Pocket Edition world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm going to build a city and I need to know where the center is. I'm using version 0.6.1. How can I figure out where the exact center is located?

Answer (score 2):

The [Minecraft Wiki](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/) is a Minecraft player's best friend. If you've never heard of it, it's an excellent site to become familiar with. For example, the article on [Pocket Edition](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_edition#Gameplay) says:

> The world size is 256x256 blocks.

So the exact centre of your world will be at the far corner of the block counted 128x128 in from one corner of the world.